# Do the Flintstones have to feed their appliances?

Tags: cartoon, the-flintstones

Granted its a cartoon, but something always puzzled me....

The **Flintstones** are a "modern stone-age family", and have all the conveniences of the modern world. These include appliances such as trash compactors, garbage disposals, radios, washing machines, dicta-birds...all manner of modern stuff.... which are essentially powered by animals. Everything from mini-mammoths to pre-historic pigs to itty bitty dino birds, there are a lot of these "Appliances" around which they use every day.

[image]

Considering there is no electricity (and these creatures wouldn't run on it anyway), but they should be powered by *something* .... **How exactly do these "items" get their power?** Do the Flintsones have to feed them regularly?

It's never been elaborated on in the cartoon; figured somebody must know something.

Comment: Nevermind who's feeding them, who's slopping out the "garbage disposal!?"  Kinda defeats the _purpose_ of a garbage disposal...

Comment: they also had working televisions and tv cameras so....

Comment: A running gag is those animals saying "it's a living".  I remember an episode, or TV movie, that showed the animals when they are off-duty, and the flintstones aren't around.  I believe they feed themselves on their own time, as they are employed, not owned.

Comment: @rld that needs to be an answer

Comment: This is some deeply dark shizzle; https://www.bleedingcool.com/2017/03/01/the-flintstones-underlines-the-slavery-parallel-of-their-appliances-lives/

Comment: @DavidW Duuuuuuude.... I haven't thought of that since I was a kid, but you make a good point!

Comment: @NKCampbell I have yet to figure a working _plausible_ aspect to that beyond animal telepathy, so I'm not even venturing there.

Comment: @rld Dude, if you can show a clip of this, I'll **gladly** accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Valorum No no... I'm not suggestting the animals are in some form of _Slavery,_ my dude, merely that as a crude form of bio-technology, they _have_ to get energy from _somewhere!_ So I'm just wondering if there was any clear answer provided in canon,

Comment: @Russhiro - As with most worldbuilding, if you start to actually consider the ethics you end up going down a very narrow and dark rabbit-hole.

Comment: @Valorum that's like considering the "ethics" of the possible parents of the Muppet Babies leaving them in the care of their Nanny literally **all the time!** I presummed it was a foster home and "Nanny" was just what they called her, because she _does_ love them like a mother. Same with the animals; never presumed any unethical treatment, but it _Does_ leave the _Specifics_ of _How_ they function in that world up to question. I'm guessing it is a type of symbiotic relationship, which is why the Flintstones would _need_ to feed these creatures, or at least give them _sum_ benefit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A running gag is those animals saying "it's a living". I remember an episode, or TV movie, that showed the animals when they are off-duty, and the flintstones aren't around. I believe they feed themselves on their own time, as they are employed, not owned.

Comment: I will try and hunt a clip down after work, I have vague memories of a 80s era made for TV special/movie..

Comment: Taking you as a person of honor, and for your logical application, I put this as an answer anyway. Thank you./

Comment: I remember hearing one or another of the appliance animals saying that on several occasions. I watched the flintstones when it first came out.